# Run Jquery Script after delete post in front end

Tags: posts, jquery, customization, trash

I have a list of posts on a page on the front end.  With each post I have created a delete button with get_delete_post_link.  This works fine but I now need to execute some jQuery after the post is deleted.  I can't figure out how to do this.
Could someone help me out?

Thank you

Comment: I don't remember the workflow for deleting: does that trigger a page refresh, or is it done by Ajax?

Comment: It refreshes the current page.  I actually worked out a way around this so I no longer need to do this, but maybe this question is still useful for others if someone can answer it.